# TensorFlow Error: "CopyCPUTensorToGPU: GPU Memcpy failed"

Tags: python, gpu, tensorflow, memcpy

I'm running the [`deepdream.ipnyb`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/deepdream/deepdream.ipynb) example that came with TensorFlow. The line `render_naive(T(layer)[:,:,:,channel])` gives me `CopyCPUTensorToGPU: GPU Memcpy failed`.

One possibility is that it's a mismatch between the notebook which is from TensorFlow HEAD and my TensorFlow installation which is from a recent pip release.

But if that were the case I would expect many more folks to have the same issue. It seems like this is a very rare bug because a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=CopyCPUTensorToGPU%3A%20GPU%20Memcpy%20failed&oq=CopyCPUTensorToGPU%3A%20GPU%20Memcpy%20failed&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58j69i60.198j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for `CopyCPUTensorToGPU: GPU Memcpy failed` yields a grand total of 5 results.

Second possibility is that this is an issue with the specific machine that I'm running on, EC2's g2.2xlarge.

Stack: EC2's g2.2xlarge machine, Python 2, Jupyter

Complete trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InternalError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-401ce587fe66> in <module>()
     35     showarray(visstd(img))
     36 
---> 37 render_naive(T(layer)[:,:,:,channel])

<ipython-input-4-401ce587fe66> in render_naive(t_obj, img0, iter_n, step)
     27     img = img0.copy()
     28     for i in xrange(iter_n):
---> 29         g, score = sess.run([t_grad, t_score], {t_input:img})
     30         # normalizing the gradient, so the same step size should work
     31         g /= g.std()+1e-8         # for different layers and networks

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict)
    347 
    348     # Run request and get response.
--> 349     results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
    350 
    351     # User may have fetched the same tensor multiple times, but we

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _do_run(self, target_list, fetch_list, feed_dict)
    421         # pylint: disable=protected-access
    422         raise errors._make_specific_exception(node_def, op, e.error_message,
--> 423                                               e.code)
    424         # pylint: enable=protected-access
    425       raise e_type, e_value, e_traceback

InternalError: CopyCPUTensorToGPU: GPU Memcpy failed
     [[Node: import/mixed3b/_197 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_1001_import/mixed3b", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

Comment: Running into the same problem if I save and re-load a CNN model. Couldn't find the solution

Comment: did you ever figure out this issue?  I am running into the same thing.

Comment: I started using this AMI and it solved my issue: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B01EYKBEQ0/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-2&qid=1464653041236